# Unable to fetch contact's Birthday

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to fetch Contact Birthday in SOQL, But got error.
My SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Birthdate  FROM Contact LIMIT 10
```

Error:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Birthdate  FROM Contact LIMIT 10
             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:18
No such column 'Birthdate' on entity 'Contact'. If you are attempting to use 
a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

[image]

[Contact Field Document by Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

How can I retrieve Birth Date From a Contact ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is fine.

It works: [image: See here]

You are getting that error because your profile does not have access to the 'Birthdate' field on Contact object.

To grant access,

1. Go to Setup > Customize > Contact > Fields
2. Click on 'Birthdate' under Contact Standard Fields
3. Click on 'Set Field-Level Security' button as shown in photo below:
   [image]
4. Check 'Visible' next to your user's profile.
   [image]
5. Save
6. Run your query again and it should be good.